# WPF - Timeout Exception cause

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I've been having some issues with one of my view models in a WPF application, where one of the tabs when saved would cause issues like app freezing, timeout, etc.

I'm fairly new to working with C# and WPF, so any help on tracing the issue would be grand. Here is an exStackTrace of an aborted transaction. I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction or where to look to fix this or gain more information on what is happening.

```
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.BeginCommit(InternalTransaction tx, Boolean asyncCommit, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Transactions.CommittableTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.InternalDispose()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.Dispose()
   at Company.AAA.Application.Client.ViewModel.StaffViewModel.<get_SaveCommand>b__376_0(Object param)
   at Company.AAA.Application.Client.RelayCommand.Execute(Object parameter)
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

ICommand bound to UI element

```
private ICommand save;
public ICommand SaveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (save == null)
        {
            save = new RelayCommand(param =>
                {
                    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
                    {
                        if (record.Id == Guid.Empty)
                        {
                            var inserted = repository.Insert(record);
                            if (inserted != null)
                            {
                                if (param == null)
                                    DXMessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully.", "Inserted", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var update = repository.SaveStaff(record, changeList);
                            if (update != null)
                            {
                                if (param == null)
                                    DXMessageBox.Show("Record saved successfully.", "Updated", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                DXMessageBox.Show("An Error occurred updating the record. Save canceled.", "Update error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                                try
                                {
                                    App.context.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, record);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    App.crashReport(ex, "Refresh");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        transaction.Complete();
                    }
                });
        }
        return save;
    }
}
```

And the function where I run SubmitChanges

```
public staffRecord SaveStaff(staffRecord rec, List<string> prev)
{
    var user = App.publicUser;
    if (user != null)
    {

        try
        {
            rec.UpdatedTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            rec.UpdatedUserId = Convert.ToInt16(user.UserId);
            rec.IsDeleted = false;

            try
            {
                var changeSet = App.context.GetChangeSet();
                if (changeSet.Updates.Count > 0)
                {
                    App.context.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
                    return rec;
                }
                else
                {
                    DXMessageBox.Show("Staff Record was not Updated, no changes found.", "Not Updated", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (ChangeConflictException cx)
            {
                App.crashReport(cx, "staffconflict");
                App.LogEntryNew("Staff", "Update Concurency clash", "BUS", "OK", "INF", "", rec.Id, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            App.crashReport(ex, "SaveStaff.StaffRepository");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Freezing / timeout sounds like the UI thread is deadlocking. Is your transaction somehow calling back into the UI (which UI thread can't process because it's waiting for transaction). Can you try doing the transaction on a different thread?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: check your -> RelayCommand
there is no try...catch. If an unhandled exception occoured, check  your log, or the eventlogs of Windows, where all logs are the regarding directly process crashes happens